# Installing Ubuntu 15.04 with windows 8.1 problem

Tags: 15.04

Ubuntu 15.04 seems to install better with windows 8.1. So, I was able to install it once and it came up with Ubuntu.  Then, I also checked if Windows worked as well. However, it immediately went into windows without the choice
for the OS part.
I reinstalled Ubuntu, but this time it gave me the error message:

```
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu first and than Windows, Windows has overwritten grub bootloader, so it will go directly to Windows. When you are trying install Ubuntu and you get error `grub-install/dev/sda` it's probably caused because issues like EFI vs. Legacy installation. Try to use Ubuntu Live CD and install on Live CD https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and try to repair boot loader, that is if you have not corrupt partitions yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is amazing. I may not clearly have stated that Windows 8.1 was there first. I followed the boot-repair procedure suggested to me in the answer and it seem to work. I did boot both in Ubunntu and in Windows.  Now, I just turned the machine on again and it comes up in Windows again without a choice for the OS.
In the process, the message it gave to me was: http://paste.ubuntu.com/118643335
I was sure that the problem was fixed but it is not the case.